# Where is the JRE lib/security directory on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, pki, java-security

I need to generate a cert and can't find this directory.  Thanks!

Comment: Certificate generation in Java is handled by the `keytool` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Folder /lib/security from JRE 8 under OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488490/where-is-the-folder-lib-security-from-jre-8-under-os-x)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the equivalent directory to jre/lib/security under OS X is:

```
/Library/Java/Home/lib/security
```

Comment: Apparently no longer.

Comment: for me it was at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security
`

Answer (score 41):

On Mavericks (OS X 10.10) with Oracle Java 8, it appears to be:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security`

Comment: On OS X 10.10.5 the accepted answer did not work for me, but this answer did.

Comment: For installation of self signed certificates or any other certs, the right cacert path on Mac OS, with JDK 1.8 is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security 

to avoid sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Answer (score 6):

The following works for 10.11.6

```
/Library/Java/Home/jre/lib/security
```

It's actually just a link to the

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/.../Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```

Comment: Looks like this is still accurate as of Catalina (10.15).

Answer (score 2):

The location I've found on MacOS Mojave with jre 1.8.0 is:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security
```

I was not trying to do any Java certificate-store stuff but needed to tweak some security settings for an applet.

Also, can you believe it's 2019 and we're still messing with this crap? ;)

Comment: Just give an answer, if you have any, rather than being sarcastic IMHO.

Comment: Sorry I ruined your day.

Comment: It's ok. I can survive.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```