# Where is the Folder /lib/security from JRE 8 under OS X?

Tags: java, macos, certificate, osx-elcapitan

I'm searching the Folder /lib/security from Java JRE 8 under OS X. Under Windows the fodler is located in the installation directory of java in the subfolder lib\security, for example: C:\Programm Files\Java\JRE_xxx\lib\security. But under OS X (El Capitan) i didn't find this folder.

When i install Java JDK is found it inside the JDK install folder, but JRe come with shipped certificates, too which are stored in the cacerts file inside the lib/security folder. So this folder must be in OS X somewhere, because when i run the Java Control Panel i can see these certificates.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java JRE are installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`. So the `lib/security` Folder is located in

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security
```

For Java JDK you have to look in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/JDK_xxx/....
```

Answer (score 10):

Its located under

```
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in /etc/java/security?

or /Library/Java/Home/lib/security?

Comment: yes i've done, but nothing there. But after i posted my question i found the answer still surprising after after a long search. See my answer for Details.